# Best (fastest) method for root finding of 6th degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

Given a polynomial on the form:

$$0=x^{6}+k_1{1}x^{5}+k_2x^{4}+k_3x^{3}+k_4x^{2}+k_5x+k_6$$

Whats the best(read: fastest) numerical root finding algorithm ?
And one which should include complex roots preferably. Assume a multiprocessor environment (for simplicity assume at least 4 processor cores) on the target machine.

Currently I have been using a companion matrix and finding eigenvalues (using the non-free intel mkl lib), but wondering if there could be better method ?

Update: Algorithm doesn't need to calculate complex if it makes any difference.

Comment: What precision are you after?

Comment: standard double precision

Comment: What are your results on/experiences with Durand-Kerner, Laguerre, Lin-Bairstow? The overhead of Jenkins-Traub might be too much for degree 6, that algorithm probably works best with degrees 15-50. The simple Newton method using complex initial points might also work well if tries with long initial jumps are cut short.

Comment: I would have to say none at this point, but interesting point about Jenkins-Traub.

Answer (score 1):

A standard algorithm is the [Jenkins–Traub algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm), which is fast and globally convergent.

Comment: I tested against RPoly++ github.com/sweeneychris/RpolyPlusPlus and that was about 5 times slower than current method. Could be more fundamental differences than the algorithm that causing it though - I mean like not utilizing multi-core or perhaps AVX instruction set, etc.